# questions about super.init and ()

Tags: swift, xcode

I am confused when you have a child class that inherit from a parent class.
First question is why use super.init? I understand override init so it can override the values that was previously set from the parent but I don't understand the use of super.init.. 
Second question is why does init have parameters? 
EDIT: Also why sometimes, the parent class also have a init??

```
class car {
    var speed = 5
    var model: String?
    var age: Int?

}

class bmw: car {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        model = "cat"
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do not substitute one unrelated question for another. The correct procedure is to accept the answer to the first question (or not) and ask a new, separate question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, there is no good reason for calling `super`. But in general any class may have properties to initialize and other initial tasks to perform, and the rule, which says that a designated initializer of a subclass must call a superclass designated initializer, guarantees that this will happen coherently both for the subclass and for the superclass.